# what type of azure blob should I use for static content

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I want to store my static website in azure blobs.
My question is, what type of blob (Page-Blob or Block-Blob) should I use for images and javascript files?

Comment: I would suggest you read this article @ allcomputers.us: [Azure Blob Storage : Windows Azure Content Delivery Network, Blob Storage Data Model](http://allcomputers.us/windows_azure/azure-blob-storage---windows-azure-content-delivery-network,-blob-storage-data-model.aspx) I think it will answer your question from a different angle.

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question. I understand that I should enable CDN, but I don't understand if the blob type affects performance when it's queried by the browser. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Block Blobs** were the [first option to come along with Azure Storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/11/using-windows-azure-page-blobs-and-how-to-efficiently-upload-and-download-page-blobs.aspx) and tend to be the most common since their goal is primarily intended for streaming (*or read-only workloads*). **Page Blobs** came along later to better support VHD mounting with random read-write block ranges.

Since you will have more frequently reading, I would push towards **Block Blobs** which will give you the best performance for downloads.

Comment: Nothing on that page says that they're recommended for small file sizes?

Comment: If something still confusing, check out the [Understanding Block Blobs and Page Blobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691964.aspx)